# On Premise Microsoft Cognitive Services

Tags: artificial-intelligence, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

The data being sent to Cognitive Services (say LUIS) might contain some information which we do not wish to expose outside the enterprise. Therefore , would like to know how can this be achieved??

Comment: Do you need that private data in LUIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For LUIS, you can set log=off in the URL you send. That will disable logging of utterances. Document is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-resources-faq.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider LUIS containers, which only sends necessary billing usage data to Azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-container-howto?tabs=v3